# How do you pass an element between chained functions in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

As you can see in the code below, I would have to search and define var img again in the chain... and I would have to keep searching and defining it for any other chained functions. I figure there has to be a better way of doing it. So, what is the proper way to pass an element down the chain for manipulation?

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var img = $(this).find('img');

    $(img).show();
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(img).hide();
    //Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined
});
```

Comment: you can extract `var img` to one scope higher

Comment: I suspect you're misunderstanding what a method 'chain' is.  There's no 'chain' in your code; there are separate event handlers which don't share anything in common other than the `e` which is `show.bs.modal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/v0shL61n/)**

You can use global variable as below.

```
var img;
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    img = $(this).find('img');

    $(img).show();
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(img).hide();
    //Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined
});
```

Also, I have prepared a sample demo, you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/hdxetakd/)

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation**

Since you are using an ID to locate image elements, the best solution is to define the element outside the scope of your chain in order to prevent multiple variable declarations (because there can only be one ID on a page at a given time).

Another thing to understand is that chaining methods is simply syntactic sugar for calling multiple functions on an object. As far as their scope goes, you might as well have called them on separate lines since they do not share any information between them.

**Example**

```
var $modalImg = $('#myModal img');

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $modalImg.show();
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $modalImg.hide();
});
```

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I was overestimating what chaining actually does, so in this case, the only way to share that var between the two functions would be to declare it higher.